# Visual Basic 6: reset ImageList-Control

Tags: vb6

following issue ...

In my project I have to reset (delete all saved images and format) an ImageList that's bound to a ListView-control. At first I unbind the ImageList from the ListView with "ListView1.Icons = Nothing". Then I clear my ImageList with "ImageList1.ListImages.Clear" ... no problem up to now. But if I wanna "rebind" (make new binding between both controls) both controls with "ListView1.Icons = ImageList1" I receive an message like "ImageList must be initialized befor use" ... and I don't know how to initialize an ImageList.

Does somebody can help me?

Greetings,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You need to add at least 1 image with `ImageList.ListImages.Add(..)` before you `set ListView1.Icons = ImageList1`

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Does Visual Basic 6 knows any commands / constants to add a dummy item to my ImageList?

Comment: Damn ... my program doesn't have an icon and shouldn't get one. ;-) But in a little testproject it works. Thanks so far. :-)

Comment: There is no "dummy item" it has to be a valid image of some form.

Comment: stick an icon in a hidden image control on the form or LoadResPicture to load one from a resource

Comment: Okay, that works up to now ... but ... in the property dialog for ImageLists I adjusted "userdefinied" for the image size. I fill my ImageList at runtime and I wanna clear it over a "delete"-button ... and then I wanna fill it with new pictures. but these new pictures could have another size as the pictures before. do u know, what I mean?

When I now initialize the ImageList at runtime with an dummy-icon, the size is fixed.

Comment: You can set the size before you add any images. After that it's fixed.